# Из вложенных массивов получить массив с числами внутри, которые содержатся во всех вложенных массивах

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть такой объект

```
               "obj": {
                    "arr1": [
                        [
                            0
                        ]
                    ],
                    "arr2": [],
                    "arr3": [
                        [
                            6,
                            7
                        ],
                        [
                            12,13
                        ]
                    ]
                }
```

Нужно получить arr1 = [0], arr2 = [], arr3 = [6,7,12,13]
Для этого вроде есть специальная функция flat, но она толи эксперементальная, то ли еще не работает, как это сделать руками?

Comment: flat() прекрасно работает. Покажите, что не получилось с flat?

Answer (score 1):

> вроде есть специальная функция flat, но она толи эксперементальная, то ли еще не работает

Все прекрасно работает...

```js
const obj = {
  "arr1": [
    [
      0
    ]
  ],
  "arr2": [],
  "arr3": [
    [
      6, 7
    ],
    [
      12, 13
    ]
  ]
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = obj[k].flat())
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение)

```
function flatten(arr) {
        const result = [...arr];
        let i = 0;

        while (i < result.length) {
            if (result[i] instanceof Array) {
                result.splice(i, 1, ...result[i]);
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```